# iOS 8 writeToFile in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to write a simple string to file, using the following code:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];
    NSString *content = @"Test Content";
    NSError *error = nil;
    [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", fileName, error);
```

But the file is'nt written and error is null.

I'm running the code in the iOS Simulator and expect the file to be written to a location like: /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85DDC17D-A771-40D9-99BE-71FF6B60D2DF/data/Containers/Data/Application/BD30A945-25DB-4ECE-B7F7-E9C20C6691C7/Documents/textfile.txt (the Path of fileName from NSLog).

Comment: "`writeToFile:atomically:encoding:`" returns a BOOL value to indicate success or failure of the writing.  In your case, does it return true or false?

Comment: It returns true. But the file hasn't been written. I've created now a test project and executed the same code and the file gets written. So probably it has somthing todo with the project?

Comment: I've copy pasted the code above in an new app and it just works. Are you sure you are using the EXACTE code as above? Also create the fileName var like: `NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"textfile.txt"];`

Comment: How did you know that the file isn't written?

Comment: Yes i'm using the exact code, as i already said above the code works for me in an empty project, it doesn't work in my current project, which was originally created for iOS 7.

Comment: @hasan83 i've checked the path of fileName via the terminal and there is no file.

Comment: There there should be a difference! I've just ran in an iOS 7 app on an iOS 8 device. Then I ran is again compiled with the iOS 8 SDK, it still works. You issue is somewhere else. But I did change this: `NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"textfile.txt"];` Ans you error is `null` because there is not error.

Comment: your file path is not like mine: /Users/hasan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/EA43BE93-615E-4676-8B4E-FCFA113BECA4/

Comment: I would use _URLs_ instead of _paths_, that would be more reliable both on device and on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

As @rckoenes pointed out it was an error in the rest of my code. I have a function that deletes all files in "documents", i just didn't remember that i had this function and because of the length of the code (>5000 lines) it was hard to find. Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

working with URLs is a bit reliable way, so I would re-work your idea slightly like e.g. this:

```
NSURL *_documentFolder = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *_fileURL = [_documentFolder URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"textFile.txt"];
NSError *_error = nil;
BOOL _success = [@"hello!" writeToURL:_fileURL atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&_error];
```

that works perfectly on simulator and on real device too, and the file `textFile.txt` will have the content `hello!`.

---

*NOTE: if the `_success` value is `FALSE`, you can get more information about the reason via a the `_error`, even if you'd just log it to the debug-console. I have not isolated the `NSString` in my example, but you can replace it with your own instance.*

Comment: lovely... a genius downvoted without leaving any comment... could the damn system be reworked finally by forcing those idiots to leave some comment? it is not helpful for the community – because personally I have no idea how I should improve of the answer. if anyone has, please leave me a hint. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

please check below code:

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *filePath = [[pathsobjectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"textfile.txt"];
   NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Test Content"];
   [temp writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what is different and why!